# number of subarrays where sum of numbers is divisible by K

Tags: algorithm, optimization, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given an array, find how many such subsequences (does not require to be contiguous) exist where sum of elements in that subarray is divisible by K.

I know an approach with complexity 2^n as given below. it is like finding all nCi where i=[0,n] and validating if sum is divisible by K. 
Please provide Pseudo Code something like linear/quadratic or n^3.

```
static int numways = 0;
void findNumOfSubArrays(int  [] arr,int index, int sum, int K) {
        if(index==arr.length) {
                if(sum%k==0) numways++;
        }
        else {
                findNumOfSubArrays(arr, index+1, sum, K);
                findNumOfSubArrays(arr, index+1, sum+arr[index], K);
        }
}
```

Comment: That approach you mentioned looks more as brute-force than divide-and-conquer, just saying

Comment: Reduce the original array to the range of [0 .. (k-1)] by modulo, then use dynamic programming to count the number of combination (one dimension is the modulo, the other dimension is the number of elements that you have summed up).

Answer (score 2):

Input - array A in length n, and natural number k.

The algorithm:

- Construct array B: for each 1 <= i <= n: B[i] = (A[i] modulo K).

Now we can use dynamic programming:

We define D[i,j] = maximum number of sub-arrays of - B[i..n] that the sum of its elements modulo k equals to j.

1 <= i <= n.
0 <= j <= k-1.

D[n,0] = if (b[n] == 0), 2. Otherwise, 1.

if j > 0 :

D[n,j] = if (B[n] modulo k) == j, than 1. Otherwise, 0.

for i < n and 0 <= j <= k-1:

D[i,j] = max{D[i+1,j], 1 + D[i+1,  D[i+1,(j-B[i]+k) modulo k)]}.

- Construct D.
- Return D[1,0].

Overall running time: O(n*k)

Comment: `D[i,j] = maximum number of sub-arrays of - B[j..n] that the sum of its elements = j` One of the `j` is `i`, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your question - i represent the starting sub-array, and j represent the sum of the sub-array we want (modulo k of course).

Comment: so isn't that a typho then? Shouldn't it be B[i..n]? :\

Comment: sorry guys.. what I meant was subsequences only.. so does this work for the subsequences ?

Comment: The above algorithm is for subsequences.

Comment: `D[i,j] = max{D[i+1,j], 1 + D[i+1, |j-(B[i] modulo k)|]}.` <- This is wrong. (Simple check, take `K = 1`, the answer should be `2^n` (or `2^n - 1` if you disallow the empty array).) The subarrays of `B[i..n]` summing to `j (mod K)` are 1. those that don't include `B[i]` and 2. those that do. Obviously the sets are disjoint, the subarrays of `B[(i+1)..k]` summing to `j` are `D[i+1,j]` in number and those that use `B[i]` are in 1-1 correspondence with the subarrays of `B[(i+1)..n]` summing to `j - B[i] (mod K)`. Thus `D[i,j] = D[i+1,j] + D[i+1,(j-B[i]+K)%K]`. Also the initialisation is wrong...

Comment: `D[n,0] = 1` (empty array), `D[n,B[n]] = 1`, `D[n,j] = 0` otherwise (if `B[n] = 0`, then `D[n,0] = 2`).

Answer (score 0):

Use an auxiliary array `A`

1) While taking input, store the current grand total in the corresponding index (this executes in `O(n)`):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
    sum += arr[i];
    A[i] = sum;
}
```

2) now,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        check that (A[j] - A[i] + arr[i]) is divisible by k
```

There you go: `O(n^2)`...

Comment: Sub Arrays are not necessarily contiguous as OP mentioned.

Comment: so you are saying among 2^n subarrays not more than n^2 subarrays could be divisible by k ?

Comment: I told the soln for Subarray...what u ppl are talking abt is Subsequence so u need to put the question in a better way.

Comment: Maybe he used a wrong term, but he wrote "does not require to be contiguous".

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, I don't think this problem can likely be solved in O(n^3) or even polynomial time, if the range of K and the range of numbers in array is unknown. Here is what I think:

Consider the following case: the N numbers in arr is something like

[1,2,4,8,16,32,...,2^(N-1)]

,

in this way, the sums of 2^N "subarrays" (that does not require to be contiguous) of arr, is exactly all the integer numbers in [0,2^N)

and asking how many of them is divisible by K, is equivalent to asking how many of integers are divisible by K in [0, 2^N).

I know the answer can be calculated directly like (2^N-1)/K (or something) in the above case. But , if we just change a few ( maybe 3? 4? ) numbers in arr randomly, to "dig some random holes" in the perfect-contiguous-integer-range [0,2^N), that makes it looks impossible to calculate the answer without going through almost every number in [0,2^N).

ok just some stupid thoughts ... could be totally wrong.

Comment: n here is the length of the array. He asked for polynomial time for n, not for any other thing that you have mentioned

Comment: and my point is exactly: this problem can not be solved in polynomial time for n

Comment: as for reference, you can see the above DP solution provided by barak takes O(n*k), which means the algorithm depends on the size of K. That's an example of [Pseudo-polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), which is not  an algorithm in polynomial time for n.

Comment: You are right, but if you assume k is constant, and n is the length pf the array, the algorithm above is O(n). If you define n as the size of the input, the above algorithm is not polynomial.